# troubles filling in a parameter with type LocalDate

Tags: java, bluej

This question is very basic but for some reason I'm not capable of finding the answer. I'm filling in the parameters of the constructor of an object, namely a cow and I want to fill in its day of birth. The parameter is of type `LocalDate`. The LocalDate entry throws an `unclosed character literal` error when I enter any combination of dates with single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, forward slashes, or commas. Which is the right manner to fill it in? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu6y9.png)

Comment: what have tried so far??

Comment: please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "2015-01-01" /'2015-01-01'/2015,01,01/ and the same combinations in reverse

Comment: If you add (at least) the segment of code for the LocalDate object, the SO community will likely find an answer to why you are having problems. To type code, simply indent four spaces before writing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use full quotation marks
so please change
`'2015-01-01'` to `"2015-01-01"`.

Comment: i have already tried this but java keeps giving an error: incompatible types:java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.time.LocalDate

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `LocalDate` object:

```
new LocalDate("2015-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalDate API's `parse()` method

```
LocalDate.parse("1989-11-14")
```